# Another は and に question for 「わたしゃキモチ悪くて見れないんだよ」

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-は

> 「わたしゃキモチ悪くて見れないんだよ」
>   It's disgusting and I can't look.

Sometimes は still confuses me. I assume I should parse this as わたしゃ(キモチ悪くて見れないんだよ) with an implied subject for 気持ち悪い i.e. 'it'.

I started reading as "I'm disgusting and ...". So the question is, is:

> 私は気持ち悪い

ambigous as a standalone statement ? Can it mean both "I am disgusting" and "It's disgusting for me"?

Can I disambiguate it by adding particle に:

> 私には気持ち悪い

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

> 私は気持ち悪い

has an inherent ambiguity whether it describes the subject's quality or feeling. Some words in English also have the problem, for example:

> I'm cold

could be both "I feel cold" or "I am cold-hearted". Thankfully Japanese has different word for each (寒い and 冷たい) so that we don't end up in confusion :)

But you could usually make use of context:

> 道路に動物の死体みたいなものがあるんだけど――わたしゃキモチ悪くて見れないんだよ
>   → *I feel disgusted and cannot look at it*
>
> 鈴木くんが目を見て話してくれないんだけど――わたしゃキモチ悪くて見れないんだよ
>   → (I think) *I am disgusting and he cannot look at me*

and so on.

> *Can I disambiguate it by adding particle に:*
>
> > *私には気持ち悪い*

Yes, but it's more like rewording because it changes the meaning a bit. Typically it means "too disgusting for me".

It may be a dirty hack, but if you say 私は気持ち**が**悪い it'll be understood almost solely as "I'm disgusted/sick".

Answer (score 7):

Yes and yes. Divorced of all context, yes 私は気持ち悪い is indeed ambiguous and yes you can help disambiguate it with に like you did. Fundamentally Japanese is a more context-dependent language than English, so this situation arises frequently.

Answer (score 5):

> I started reading as "I'm disgusting and ...". So the question is, is:
>
> > 私は気持ち悪い
>
> ambigous as a standalone statement ? Can it mean both "I am disgusting" and "It's disgusting for me"?

Yes. If he or she is talking about him or her, it means "I am disgusting"; otherwise it means "It's disgusting for me".

> Can I disambiguate it by adding particle に:
>
> > 私には気持ち悪い

Yes. You can also say it this way

> 気持ち悪い

or

> 気持ち悪く感じる(思う)